# Problem when splitting data: KeyError: "None of [Int64Index([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13], dtype='int64')] are in the [columns]"

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, train-test-split

I am attempting to execute a train test split on some data, wine.data but when initializing x and y:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd
from sklearn.neural_network import MLPClassifier
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from sklearn.metrics import accuracy_score
from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler

from sklearn.model_selection import cross_val_score

wine =  pd.read_csv("https://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/machine-learning-databases/wine/wine.data")

print(wine.shape)
wine.head()
X = wine[np.arange(1,14)]
y = wine[0]
```

The rest of the code below this segment will not run as I get the error message:

```
KeyError: "None of [Int64Index([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13], dtype='int64')] are in the [columns]"
```

I have attempted to resolve this by changing the range of the X value or changing the np.arange function but neither help the problem.

**Any help or advice would be greatly appreciated, thank you!**

Comment: You dataframe has the following columns `Index(['1', '14.23', '1.71', '2.43', '15.6', '127', '2.8', '3.06', '.28',
       '2.29', '5.64', '1.04', '3.92', '1065'],
      dtype='object')` so.. the error message is correct. What columns did you expect?

Comment: I was expecting the column numbers from 0 to 13

Comment: You should print your dataframe to see how it looks like... anyway I posted the solution already.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You forgot to add `header=None` to the dataframe constructor. The csv you are downloading doesn't have a header line. So, if you don't specify `header=None`, the first line of data will be used as the header.

Try with

```
wine =  pd.read_csv(
    "https://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/machine-learning-databases/wine/wine.data",
    header=None
)
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you trying to select the columns by their positions ?
If that so, try :

```
X = wine.iloc[:,np.arange(1,14)]
y = wine.iloc[:, 0]
```